# Indigo on Trusty

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

So I wanted to go ahead of time and install indigo on ubuntu trusty (14.04), but found out the binaries are incomplete? ros-indigo-desktop* doesn't exist at least. Many binaries do seem to exist, I thought maybe I could install all of them and have a working ROS, but alas, no catkin_make even.

Is this a matter of waiting? Or can I do something? (preferably without going towards installing from source)

Best regards,
Hans

edit: Just tried to build from source as well, the rosinstall_generator fails with :

```
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: desktop-full
No packages/stacks left after ignoring not released
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154806/indigo-on-trusty/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on 2015-09-11**:
Hi.
Did you manage to sort out this problem?
It is now well past may, and i still can't get this installed on ubuntu 14.04.03.
Cheers

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-09-11**:
You have a different problem and are not running 14.04.3 but 15.04: http://answers.ros.org/question/217485/ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-140403-e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all packages for desktop-full have been released into Indigo yet. As you mention you can get a lot of packages already but indigo is still in pre-release stage.

Indigo's target release date is in May. http://wiki.ros.org/indigo

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-04-18**:
Thank you for your reply. I got a long way compiling ros_comm and installing the rest.

**Comment by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on 2015-09-11**:
I still get this problem. Has indigo not yet been released for trusty, or what is the deal?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-09-11**:
No, it's been out for a long time. Please ask a new question with full details of what you're doing and what's failing if you're still having trouble.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-09-11**:
Found your question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/217485/ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-140403-e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/